# Say I have a 280 character message that uses only 26 upper case letters?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to split the message into 3 segments (the first x letters, the next y letters, and the last 280-x-y letters). How many ways could the message be partitioned, assuming each segment has at least one letter?

Is is like 26 choose 1 * 26 choose 1 * 26 choose two?

These are choose formulas times each other.

Answer (score 1):

If the sizes are $x,y,z$ you want the number of $>0$ integer solutions to

$x+y+z=280$

which is the same as the number of $\ge 0$ integer solutions to

$x+y+z=277$ (taking the $1$ for granted) and this number is given by a well-known combinatorial formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).)